# Interactive display with large set of RGB data

Tags: javascript, html, web

Given that I have a 2D array of RGB points, what is the best way to display the image created by this data? Furthermore, how can I zoom and pan the image with mouse events. I have attempted to use a canvas and the putImageaData method but canvas translates and scale don't seem to effect the plotted image.